# Returning a Poco session without creating new connection

Tags: c++, c++11, session, odbc, poco-libraries

Depending on if a condition is met I want to return a session but don't want to create a new connection.

```
Poco::Data::Session initialise(){
 if(some condition){
   Poco::Data::Session temp1('odbc',someSettings1)
   return temp1

  }else{
   Poco::Data::Session temp2('odbc',someSettings2)   
   return temp2
   }
}

int main(){
 Poco::Data::Session  sess(initialise());
}
```

1. Does the above create a new connection when I pass the function as a constructor argument?
2. Would it make a difference if I returned it as an anonymous object i.e. `return Poco::Data::Session('odbc',someSettings1)`
3. Or is there a better way overall to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

1. yes
2. no
3. To prevent the creation of new connection, make one of the sessions in the function static:

   Poco::Data::Session initialise()
   {
   static Poco::Data::Session temp1('odbc',someSettings1);
   if(some condition)
   return temp1
   else
   {
   Poco::Data::Session temp2('odbc',someSettings2)
   return temp2
   }
   }

   int main(){
   Poco::Data::Session  sess(initialise());
   }

Comment: not sure why code formatting does not work - I selected the code and clicked {}